# What is the maximum size of RTP Header?

Tags: voip, rtp

I am working on bandwidth estimations for VoIP calls. I want to know the maximum size of RTP header. I looked on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol#Packet_header) but only the minimum size is available. I tried to calculate manually the number of bits used in the header but the field:

"**Header extension:** (optional) The first 32-bit word contains a profile-specific identifier (16 bits) and a length specifier (16 bits) that indicates the length of the extension (EHL = extension header length) in 32-bit units, excluding the 32 bits of the extension header"

is confusing me. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The header structure in the wiki page shows that the header size depends on the value of the CC field (bits 4-7). These four bits can hold at most 15, so the header size will be 128 + 32 x CC = 128 + 15 * 32 = 608 bits = 76 bytes.

For more info, see [RFC 3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550).

Comment: Oops, my bad- it will be 608 _bits_, which means 76 bytes. Fixed my answer.

Comment: 15 x 4 = 60 (bytes) max for the CC, the base header is 12 bytes and it contains CC, finally  60 + 12 = 72.